# Wake up a remote computer connected behind a router

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, wake-on-lan

I want to switch on a remote computer running debian linux connected behind a wireless router through LAN with my laptop which is connected to the router over a wireless connection. I have wakeonlan installed it gives Support Wake-on  as "pumbg" and wake-on as "g" when i run ethtool command through terminal. Please help.

Comment: If your router supports sending WOL packet on its own, like mikrotik routers, you can SSH to the router and send the packet from there. I patched gwakeonlan utility on Linux to support this here: https://github.com/muflone/gwakeonlan/compare/master...the-moisrex:gwakeonlan:master

Answer (score 2):

Nope.
See, the problem is that this would require something on the computer to listen to a wake up IP packet.

SAdly, WakeOnLan support is not based on IP but on special ethernet packets, and those will not traverse the router.

If you can log into your router and issue a wake on lan from there, it would work. But then... this is not a professional setup, and thus off topic on this site.